# What's the best way to break closed polyline using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, java, splitting

I have a polyline feature class with several closed lines (the start point = the end point). I need to break these lines in two features, using ArcObjects (doesn't matter Java, VB or C#).

I have already detected these closed lines in this way:

```
IFeatureCursor featureCursor = lineFeatureClass.search(null, false);
        IFeature feature = null;
        while((feature = featureCursor.nextFeature()) != null) {
            IGeometry geometry = feature.getShape();
            IPolyline polyline = (IPolyline)geometry;
            if(polyline.isClosed()) {
                log.info("closed line detected");
                boolean[] splitHappened = new boolean[1];
                int[] newPartIndex = new int[1];
                int[] newSegmentIndex = new int[1];
                polyline.splitAtDistance(0.5, true, true, splitHappened, newPartIndex, newSegmentIndex);

            }
        }
```

Now, I get a polyline composed of 2 parts (or path), and I don't know how to get them.

Then, I need to remove the second path from the current feature, and create a new feature with the second path as a geometry and the same attribute values.

Does anyone know what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but there are geoprocessing tools you can call in ArcObjects to seperate multipart features into individual features: (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003r000000)

Comment: yes, maybe it's a good way to split polylines as multipart, and then to get singleparts with the geoprocessing tool. Nevertheless, I would prefer not to create a new feature class.

Answer (score 1):

polyline.splitAtDistance doesn't actually split a polyline. All you have to do is cast your IFeature as IFeatureEdit and use the method IFeatureEdit.Split(). This will create two separate features.